# Wordpress issue..CSS nav shifts under a different page

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, shift

When its the homepage, the nav is aligned but when I click to another page, I shifts and only the nav section shifts. Please help!! Thank you!!

Homepage:
http://guntherkoo.com/

Page:
http://guntherkoo.com/portfolio/

Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for `reset.css` is local, so it's only found at the web root.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Change it to this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Note that there are several links included there with the same problem (your js).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know it made a difference cause it read the file =X but, THANK YOU for that!